# how do I make node child_process exec continuously

Tags: node.js, child-process

How to `exec` continuously? e.g. `ls` after `cd`?

I tried

```
exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('cd ~/', 
  function(){
    exec('ls'),
    function(err, stdout, stderr){
      console.log(stdout); // this logs current dir but not ~/'s
    }
  }
)

exec('cd ~/').exec('ls', function(err, stdout, stderr){
  console.log(stdout);
})//this also fails because first exec returns a ChildProcess Object but not itself.
```

Comment: Are `cd` and `ls` the only commands you want? If so, why not just use Node's `fs` module?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is not possible to do this because exec and spawn creates a new process. But there is a way to simulate this. You can start a process with exec and execute multiple commands in the same time:
In the command line if you want to execute 3 commands on the same line you would write:

```
cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3
```

So, all 3 commands run in the same process and have access to the context modified by the previous executed commands.
Let's take your example, you want to execute cd ../ and after that to execute dir and to view the previous directory list.
In cmd you shoud write:

```
cd../ & dir
```

From node js you can start a process with exec and to tell it to start another node instance that will evaluate an inline script:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var script = "var exec = require('child_process').exec;exec('dir',function(e,d,er){console.log(d);});";
script = '"'+script+'"';//enclose the inline script with "" because it contains spaces
var cmd2 = 'node -e '+script;
var cd = exec('cd ../ &'+cmd2,function(err,stdout,strerr)
{
    console.log(stdout);//this would work
})
```

If you just want to change the current directory you should check the documentation about it http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: That does not seem right, you should use the child_process spawn function, if you want to run multiple commands. The child_process exec is meant to only run once and then return the output in a buffer.

Comment: You can also use && operator instead of & ins `exec`. It runs commands one after another and only if the previous one exited without error. So `cd ../ && ls` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nodejs promisify and async/await:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const exec = promisify(require('child_process').exec);

export default async function () {
  const cpu = await exec('top -bn1');
  const disk = await exec('df -h');
  const memory = await exec('free -m');

  const payload = {
    cpu,
    disk,
    memory,
  };

 return payload
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `cd` first, better use `process.chdir('~/')`. Then single `exec()` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can call exec with cwd param like so:

```
exec('ls -a', {
    cwd: '/Users/user'
}, (err, stdout) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);           
    } else {
        console.log(stdout);
    }
})
```

But beware, cwd doesn't understand '~'. You can use process.env.HOME instead.