# Is it possible to run an npm script in the current context using the source operator?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I'm trying to write a simple Node.js CLI to more easily navigate directories. For the sake of simplicity, let's say this is the CLI I'm trying to make:

test.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log('hey there');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('cd ~/code/');
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Example CLI that needs to run in current context",
  "bin": {
    "myScript": "test.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.*",
    "npm": "1.2.*"
  }
}
```

With both of those in the same folder, running `npm link` will create the CLI. After that, if I run `myScript`, it outputs "hey there" but doesn't change directories. I know that this is because myScript is run in it's own subshell, which is subsequently terminated. I've read [here](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) about the source operator and found that it's used like such:

```
. filename [arguments]
```

I've tried doing `. myScript` to force my code to run in the current context. However, by using the source operator, the code is interpreted as bash instead of js. Here's the error I get:

```
-bash: /Users/dallinosmun/.nvm/v0.10.21/bin/myScript: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /Users/dallinosmun/.nvm/v0.10.21/bin/myScript: line 3: `var exec = require('child_process').exec;'
```

So, any ideas on how to get a Node.js CLI to run in the current context?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible since the exec command starts a new process.
But this is a link on a way to bypass the problem:

[how do I make node child_process exec continuously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427075/how-do-i-make-node-child-process-exec-continuously)

Comment: Everything is possible especially with Node.